# Custom rendering a radioselect in django form / accessing single element?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a form like this:

```
CHOICES = [  
           ('a', 'a_value'),  
           ('b', 'b_value'),  
           ('c', 'c_value')  
]  

self.fields["choice"] = forms.ChoiceField(  
    widget=RadioSelect(),  
    choices=CHOICES,   
)
```

How can I select a single element of this form field in my template? I want to be able to do something like:

```
<tr><td>{{form.choice.a}}</td><td>some custom extra field</td></tr>
```

Or is there another way to change how the RadioSelect is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this via parameters or something, the way it is rendered is hardcoded in its widget class! See eg. http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py: RadioSelect.render (->RadioFieldRenderer.render); subclass it and override the render method, then use it in your form `myfield = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=MyWidget(...))`.

Comment: Just one more thing..is there a way to pass arguments to my subclassed renderer? When I try to pass arguments now, it says the object is not callable..

Answer (score 8):

See full doc -
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect

```
{% for radio in form.my_radio_select %}
- {{ radio.choice_label }}
- {{ radio.tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I labored over this for a few hours trying to find some way to use a custom renderer on a RadioSelect, but there is no way to pass in the choice number. Instead I went for a kludgey, but simple approach. In added an `__init__` function to my form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.radiofield_choice = re.findall(r'<li>(.+?)</li>',
                                        unicode(self['radiofield_name']))
```

That uses the RadioSelect's default render to create the widget, and then parses out the individual choice HTML. You could even combine that with the defined choices to create a dictionary instead of a list.

In my template I used `{{ form.radiofield_choice.0|safe }}` to render just the first item. Increment the zero to get the other items.

If, for some reason, only the input fields without enclosing labels are needed, use `r'(<input.+/>)'`.